# CSS Why is the last li not being targeted by li:nth-child(odd) or li:nth-child(even)?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

This is pretty straightforward.

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<ul id="myContactList">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
            <li>item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

and the trouble maker CSS:

```
ul#myContactList>li>ul>li {
    float:left; /* Trouble maker */
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekXjy/1/).

Why isn't the last ul#myContactList>li being targeted by li:nth-child(odd)?

Thanks in advance, cheers! :)

Comment: I can't see the problem? The last ul#myContactList>li is being targeted by li:nth-child(even)?

Comment: This is one of those times I ask, "why *aren't* you using a table for this?"

Comment: Why not just use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` on the li's? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ekXjy/5/

Comment: @j08691 inline-block will not work in older IE-s..

Comment: "If the HTML data you need to render is tabular (e.g.it contains multiple columns and rows) - use a table." Table's are only "**dead**" for layout purposes.

Comment: OK I just spent 5 minutes converting your nested lists into a table. [You're welcome.](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/ekXjy/7)

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, but I need an unordered list to make it work the way I want it to :) The table structure is too rigid.

Comment: @Amoguai what are your exact needs? Based on what I saw you were defining a table and a table makes more sense from what I can see. E.g. the accepted solution (or at least the JS Fiddle) fails **horribly** on IE7... (and I'm guessing IE8)

Comment: @scunliffe When I hover a row, it expands a div inside it, to show more information about that contact. This div takes 100% of the list's width and each div contains information about that particular contact. This is not possible using the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is targeting it, but you have an issue with the floats not being cleared in the last list item. See http://jsfiddle.net/ekXjy/4/ (specifically line 20 of the CSS, which causes a new float context for each list item).

```
ul#myContactList>li>ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden; /* New style, to clear the floats contained within */
}
```

The clear:both you had for ul#myContactList>li>ul clears the floats for the list items preceding the last one, but nothing cleared the floats in the last item. Using overflow:hidden to give each list item its own block context fixes that.

Comment: Thank you :) The 'ul#myContactList>li>ul' selector is supposed to select all ul's inside ul#myContactsList>li. Why isn't the last item cleared?

Comment: It does select all `<ul>`s inside `ul#myContactsList>li`. However, `clear:both` doesn't clear floats **within** the element, only elements **before** it. Using `overflow:hidden` gives the element a new float context, therefore clearing the elements within it.